# Discontinuous range of input cells in a two-argument function in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I cannot make discontinuous range of input cells such as `(A2:A2;A4:A5)` work in two-argument (and perhaps multiple-argument) functions in Excel: the following does not yield any error message, but yields `#VALUE`

```
=COVARIANCE.S((A2:A2;A4:A5);(B2:B2;B4:B5))
```

How could I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array or numbers with an array form of Index:

```
INDEX(A:A,N(IF(A2:A5<>"",ROW(A2:A5))))
```

This will return every cell that is not null A2:A5 as an array to the formula.

This works for some formula but not all.

It does work in `Slope` and `Intercept`

```
=INTERCEPT(INDEX(A:A,N(IF(A2:A5<>"",ROW(A2:A5)))),INDEX(B:B,N(IF(A2:A5<>"",ROW(A2:A5)))))
=SLOPE(INDEX(A:A,N(IF(A2:A5<>"",ROW(A2:A5)))),INDEX(B:B,N(IF(A2:A5<>"",ROW(A2:A5)))))
```

(The Second set is to show correct output)

[image]

As you can see it skips the `99` in B3 and only returns the `1,2,3` in the other cells.

We can also adjust it to skip non numeric:

```
INDEX(A:A,N(IF(ISNUMBER(A2:A5),ROW(A2:A5))))
```

The idea is the it creates an array of row numbers and supplies that to the INDEX which then returns all the numbers in that row.

Being an array formula one would need to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: This is very interesting! What about the case where A2 and B2 are of exactly the same type as the other cells in columns A and B? I cannot think of any meaningful condition that A3 would satisfy while the rest of cells in column A would not satisfy (or vice versa). I explicitly want to kick one row out for a "subjective" reason. (I am implementing leave-one-out cross validation.)

Comment: @RichardHardy then your condition of your IF would be `Row(A2:A5)<>3` instead of `A2:A5<>""`.

Comment: If you want Multiple rows it does get a little trickier.  Say you do not want 3 and 5:  You will need to use `*` to multiply two Boolean statements: `(Row(A2:A5)<>3)*(Row(A2:A5)<>5)`

Answer (score 0):

This formula is simply not about discontinuous range of input cells, it is imagined as calculation with continuous ranges. It returned `#VALUE` error because you maybe satisfied the form but definition of overall formula is wrong. If you don't have many data to calculate, you can always do it manually. 
See this example:

[image: Example]

In the Example file you can see generic formulas and a small example like yours.

You can always copy the data into another sheet and make necessary calculation when feeling trapped or lacking time to finish what you need.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping I could somehow use the formula directly. `COVARIANCE.S` is just an example, I need this to work for some other two-argument functions that are even more tedious than `COVARIANCE.S`, e.g. `INTERCEPT` and `SLOPE`... So in summary, are you saying there is no way I could input a discontinuous range into such functions? I was hoping I could trick the function to take a discontinuous input somehow, that would be a quick and convenient solution.

Comment: @Miloš: You have convinced me that you are knowledgeable about Excel, knowledgeable about statistics, and somewhat fluent in English.  And it’s clear that you have put some thought and effort into this.  But I’m not clear what your answer is. Are you saying that Excel simply can’t process discontinuous ranges, and, if you want to process data in a discontinuous range, you have to throw Excel and its worksheet functions out the window, and just do everything manually?  I believe that that’s not true.